# Python Globals() dosen't interpret a tkinter grid function key in a for loop

Tags: python, loops, tkinter, dynamic, key

I am new here I am trying to learn python and I decided to create an application in python for windows and linux who calcul salary. For the windows I am using the Tkinter library. The code below is for buttons of every days of january I tried to optimize my code using loop for. But there are some days I can't figure out how to sove a problem. I created variadble dynamically with the first loop but for my others loop who place and make appear in a grid every buttons of my month It make me the following error :

```
> Exception in Tkinter callback Traceback (most recent call last):  
> File "/usr/lib/python3.9/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
>     return self.func(*args)   File "/home/thimoty/CloudThimoty/Tech/ProjetDev/CalculHeuresSalaire/main.py",
> line 316, in listdaysjanvier
>     globals()[f'buttondaysjanvier{dynamicdaysjanviergridrow1}.grid'](f'row=1,
> column={columnrow1daysjanvier}') KeyError: 'buttondaysjanvier0.grid'
```

So my question is the following I am trying with my dynamic variable to something like that :

```
> buttondaysjanvier15.grid(row=1, column=1)
```

It is look like it don't take what there is in () with my error so my how can I do for my globals() to interpret my part who is in to call the buttondaysjanvier15.grid function ? Have a nice day guys !

```
def listdaysjanvier(self):
    global recordedmonth
    recordedmonth = months[0]
    for dynamicdaysjanvier in range(0, 30):
        globals()[f"buttonsdaysjanvier{dynamicdaysjanvier}"] = f"Button(window, text=days[{dynamicdaysjanvier}] + ' ' + months[0], command=buttonfunction.buttonday{dynamicdaysjanvier})"
    print(buttonsdaysjanvier15)

    for columnrow1daysjanvier, dynamicdaysjanviergridrow1 in zip(range(1, 5), range(0, 4)):
        globals()[f'buttondaysjanvier{dynamicdaysjanviergridrow1}.grid'](f'row=1, column={columnrow1daysjanvier}')

    for columnrow2daysjanvier, dynamicdaysjanviergridrow2 in zip(range(1, 5), range(5, 9)):
        globals()[f'buttondaysjanvier{dynamicdaysjanviergridrow2}.grid'](f'row=2, column={columnrow2daysjanvier}')

    for columnrow3daysjanvier, dynamicdaysjanviergridrow3 in zip(range(1, 5), range(10, 14)):
        globals()[f'buttondaysjanvier{dynamicdaysjanviergridrow3}.grid'](f'row=3, column={columnrow3daysjanvier}')

    for columnrow4daysjanvier, dynamicdaysjanviergridrow4 in zip(range(1, 5), range(15, 19)):
        globals()[f'buttondaysjanvier{dynamicdaysjanviergridrow4}.grid'](f'row=4, column={columnrow4daysjanvier}')

    for columnrow5daysjanvier, dynamicdaysjanviergridrow5 in zip(range(1, 5), range(20, 24)):
        globals()[f'buttondaysjanvier{dynamicdaysjanviergridrow5}.grid'](f'row=5, column={columnrow5daysjanvier}')

    for columnrow6daysjanvier, dynamicdaysjanviergridrow6 in zip(range(1, 5), range(25, 29)):
        globals()[f'buttondaysjanvier{dynamicdaysjanviergridrow6}.grid'](f'row=6, column={columnrow6daysjanvier}')

    for columnrow7daysjanvier, dynamicdaysjanviergridrow7 in zip(range(1, 5), range(30)):
        globals()[f'buttondaysjanvier{dynamicdaysjanviergridrow7}.grid'](f'row=7, column={columnrow7daysjanvier}')

    self.buttonmonths1.destroy()
    self.buttonmonths2.destroy()
    self.buttonmonths3.destroy()
    self.buttonmonths4.destroy()
    self.buttonmonths5.destroy()
    self.buttonmonths6.destroy()
    self.buttonmonths7.destroy()
    self.buttonmonths8.destroy()
    self.buttonmonths9.destroy()
    self.buttonmonths10.destroy()
    self.buttonmonths11.destroy()
    self.buttonmonths12.destroy()
    self.buttonmonthsback.destroy()
```

Comment: Don't use `globals()`.

Comment: What do you use ?

Comment: In your case probably something like dictionary or a list to contain all the similiar variables.

Comment: Why are you formatted widget? for columnrow7daysjanvier, dynamicdaysjanviergridrow7 in zip(range(1, 5), range(30)):
        globals()[f'buttondaysjanvier{dynamicdaysjanviergridrow7}.grid'](f'row=7, column={columnrow7daysjanvier}'). U shouldn't f-string in widget grid.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you are trying to create a calendar in tk. There are already pre-implemented calendar widgets that are third party libraries which you could use.

There is also some brilliant features build in to python that help you to create a calendar. The below example shows how you can use the `calendar` module to get the days which would appear on the calendar for a specified month (including the days either side).

```
import tkinter as tk
import datetime
import calendar

class Calendar(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent,*kw,**kwargs):
        month = kwargs.pop('month',1)
        year = kwargs.pop('year',2022)
        super().__init__(parent,*kw,**kwargs)
        cal = calendar.Calendar()
        for idx,dow in enumerate("Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat Sun".split()):
            tk.Label(self,text=dow).grid(row=0,column=idx)
        for dayIdx,day in enumerate(cal.itermonthdates(year,month)):
            dayBtn = tk.Button(self,text=f"{day}")
            dayBtn['command'] = lambda x=day: self.pressed(x)
            dayBtn.grid(row=(dayIdx//7)+1,column=dayIdx%7)

    def pressed(self, day):
        print(f"You pressed day {day}")

root = tk.Tk()
month = Calendar(root,month=3,year=2022)
month.grid()

root.mainloop()
```

This will create a calendar for March 2022 (change the days if you want) and when you click on the button, it will print to the console what day you pressed. No need to use globals.